# MVC3 and MVC4 in same solution

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, incompatibility

I have refereed old questions and found that people face many issues after installing mvc3 and MVC4 on same machine.

My question is how is your recent experience for the same and how the mixture works for you guys.

I want to create one solution which will have four projects out of them two are MVC projects. One is MVC3 and another is MVC4.

Let me know your views on this.

Thanks,
Jigar

Comment: how the mixture works for you?

Comment: @Mark Sure I will let you know my experience. Are you in same situation?

Comment: @Mark The mixture works for me like a charm, but to get it working I first need to un-install MVC4 and then start with MVC3 and then install MVC4 again. I am not sure this happens to other as well but to me it works fine after this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short - there shouldn't be a problem.  Once 3 & 4 are both installed, the two use different project templates and the references to the MVC assemblies are specifically targetted at the correct versions.

Beyond that, the web.configs of the two sites then determine the other assemblies that are used - and since they are seeded by the project templates they will be correct.

Now, if you were asking about having 3 & 4 in the same *project*, that would be another story.  But then you wouldn't do that.

It's true there are a few known issues with the Razor editor and stuff like that - but none of those are show-stoppers and are almost certainly likely to have been fixed by the time v4 RTMs.